# undefined method `permit' for Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The params is as follows

```
{
  "orders"=>[
    <ActionController: : Parameters{
      "line_items"=>[
        {
          "id"=>2807935,
          "segment_type"=>"DrivingSegment",
        }
      ],
      "order_id"=>484372,
      "calling_order_id"=>484371
    }permitted: false>
  ],
}permitted: false>
```

The code is as follows

```
 def update
          order_params.each do |order_param|
            order = Order.find(order_param[:order_id])
            order.assign_attributes({
              line_items_attributes: order_param[:line_items]
            })
            ...
          end
          render json: {}, status: :ok
        end

   

def order_params
      params
        .require(:orders)
        .permit(
          line_items: %i[
            id
            segment_type
          ],
          :order_id
        )
    end
```

As you can see, orders is an array. Each order has a line items array.
When i try to **assign_attributes** i am getting the following error **undefined method `permit' for Array**

Any idea on how to permit params correctly here??

Answer (score 0):

given the nature of your params, you can skip the require and just permit

`order_params.permit(orders: [line_items: [:id, : segment_type], :order_id])`

you can see https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters#nested-parameters for more examples